# How to get the count of rows from a table in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two tables:

```
id  category    status
1   test        1
2   test1       1
3   test2       1
```

This is the `group_master` table.

```
groupid     groupname   groupmaster 
1           yy          1
2           xx          1
3           yyyy                1
4           xrx         1
5           yy          2
6           xx          2
7           yyyy                2
8           xfgdrx              3
```

This is the `membergroup` table.

The `group_master.id` is same as in `membergroup.groupmaster`.That menas i want to get each row from first table and also want to get the count from second table

That means:

```
id  category    status  Count
1   test        1       4
2   test1       1       3
3   test2       1       1
```

This is the result i want to get.

How can i do this in Cakephp with pagination ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

You need to **JOIN** both tables and do a **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT g.id,g.category,g.status,count(*) as Count
FROM   group_master g
JOIN   membergroup m
ON     g.id=m.groupmaster
GROUP BY g.id,g.category,g.status
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3c18/2)